# In JShell, how to load Java code from a string?

Tags: java, jshell

I have implemented a method that generates Java code:

```java
public static String generate() { ... }
```

It returns Java code as a `String`, i.e. I might get

```java
"public class X { public static String x() { return \"x\"; } }"
```

as a value returned by `generate`. Now, I am in a [JShell Tool (JEP-222)](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/222) session, and I can call `generate`, but I fail to load *the result of `generate`* into JShell itself.

Ideally I'd like to achieve the following

```
jshell> eval(generate());
|  created class X

jshell> X.x();
$2 ==> "x"
```

In the above (hypothetical) JShell sesssion, `eval` is the function that I am looking for.

Possible solutions I already tried:

- I know that this would be possible by calling `JShell#eval` but I failed to obtain the `JShell` object that represents the currently running JShell.
- It might be that there is some facility in JShell that allows lifting a `String` to a Snippet. I couldn't find something like that, but if there is, it might be helpful.
- I know that I can `/open` a file, so it might be possible to write the `String` to a file and then open/load it. However this is a two-step process, and I would prefer to have a solution that is simpler.